# SVG clippath fill image

Tags: svg, clip-path

I want to do a clippath with this svg but not working...

https://sendeyo.com/show/a1bd93cc13

I want my clippath to fill the image.

```css
.apropos__img{
        width:30vw;
        height:30vw;
        object-fit: cover;
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
        clip-path: url(#myClip);
        float:right;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/600/600" class="apropos__img">
      <svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path class="st0" d="M187.3,78.7c0,49.8-57.1,121.3-104,121.3S0,128.6,0,78.7C0,28.7,36.4,0,83.3,0S187.3,28.7,187.3,78.7z"/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Thanks!

Comment: objectBoundingBox units range is 0..1 so numbers like 187.3 are far far too large.

Comment: you may add `transform="scale(0.005)"` to the path inside clipPath